# Deploy GitLab to Google Kubernetes Engine using Google Cloud Marketplace

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I'm installing GitLab on a cluster in GCP, I'm following this [gitlab guide](https://gitlab.com/charts/deploy-image-helm-base/blob/master/README.md), but in the step of `Clone this repo`, when running:

```
gcloud source repos clone google-marketplace-k8s-app-tools --project = k8s-marketplace-eap
```

I get an error:

```
bastian_silva_0100 @ ci-basty: ~ $ gcloud source repos clone google-marketplace-k8s- app-tools --project = k8s-marketplace-eap

ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you used working gitlab credentials?

Comment: At the time he asks me, he admitted them, however he gives me the error.

Comment: So there was no errors when you cloned the repo using `git clone`? You can also try remove the whole `.git` files and cloning it again, pay attention to the errors.